# I want only matching string using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string `"myname 18-may 1234"` and I want only `"myname"` from whole string using a regex.

I tried using the `\b(^[a-zA-Z]*)\b` regex and that gave me `"myname"` as a result.

But when the string changes to `"1234 myname 18-may"` the regex does not return `"myname"`. Please suggest the correct way to select only `"myname"` whole word.

Is it also possible - given the string in
"1234 myname 18-may" format - to get `myname` only, not `may`?

Comment: but evry time strring is not in "myname 18-may 1234" in this format also some time in "18-may myname " in this format so that time this is not better way

Comment: What are all the formats the text can be? I believe `\b([a-zA-Z]+)\b` should be enough. Pick the first match.

Comment: can someone explain Why down vote to this question?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Sure. It isn't clear what are all the expected formats. OP is introducing new formats now after the answers are posted.

Comment: ya right the people donot have any answer so that give down vote

Comment: but the question was clear. also the OP showed what he tried. and what the issue is. i dont think the Op need to put all possible formats here. because he said "_I want only "myname" from whole string using regex_" i assume that myname can be anywhere. @SriramSakthivel

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary No the answer depends on what are all the possible formats. So all possible formats must have been in the initial question. Otherwise answerers are wasting their time in something which doesn't help OP.

Comment: The reason why the question is downvoted is in poor English, I guess. I tried to fix the major linguistic issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## UPDATE

Judging by your feedback to your other question you might need

```
(?<!\p{L})\p{L}+(?!\p{L})
```

## ORIGINAL ANSWER

I have come up with a lighter regex that relies on the specific nature of your data (just a couple of words in the string, only one is whole word):

```
\b(?<!-)\p{L}+\b
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb(%3F%3C!-)%5Cp%7BL%7D%2B%5Cb&i=myname%2018-may%201234%0D%0A1234%20myname%2018-may%0D%0A18-may%20myname)

Or even a [more restrictive regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5E%7C%5Cs)%5Cp%7BL%7D%2B(%3F%3D%5Cs%7C%24)&i=myname%2018-may%201234%0D%0A1234%20myname%2018-may%0D%0A18-may%20myname) that finds a match only between (white)spaces and string start/end:

```
(?<=^|\s)\p{L}+(?=\s|$)
```

The following regex is context-dependent:

```
\p{L}+(?=\s+\d{1,2}-\p{L}{3}\b)
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cp%7BL%7D%2B(%3F%3D%5Cs%2B%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D-%5Cp%7BL%7D%7B3%7D%5Cb)&i=myname%2018-may%201234%0D%0A1234%20myname%2018-may)

This will match only the word `myname`.

The regex means:

- `\p{L}+` - Match 1 or more Unicode letters...
- `(?=\s+\d{1,2}-\p{L}{3}\b)` - until it finds 1 or more whitespaces (`\s+`) followed with 1 or 2 digits, followed with a hyphen and 3 Unicode letters (`\p{L}{3}`) which is a whole word (`\b`). This construction is a positive look-ahead that only checks if something can be found after the current position in the string, but it does not "consume" text.

Since the date may come before the string, you can add an alternation:

```
\p{L}+(?=[ ]+\d{1,2}-\p{L}{3}\b)|(?<=\d{1,2}-\p{L}{3}[ ]+)\p{L}+
```

See [another demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cp%7bL%7d%2b(%3f%3d%5b+%5d%2b%5cd%7b1%2c2%7d-%5cp%7bL%7d%7b3%7d%5cb)%7c(%3f%3c%3d%5cd%7b1%2c2%7d-%5cp%7bL%7d%7b3%7d%5b+%5d%2b)%5cp%7bL%7d%2b&i=myname+18-may+1234%0d%0a1234+myname+18-may%0d%0a18-may+myname)

The `(?<=\d{1,2}-\p{L}{3}\s+)` is a *look-behind* that checks for the same thing (almost) as the look-ahead, but *before* the `myname`.

Comment: but this not match in this "1234 18-may myname " string

Comment: In C#, the regex will work like this: `var rx = new Regex(@"\b(?<!-)\p{L}+\b"); var res = rx.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).ToList();`

Comment: can we make same for digit we get ony number 804 ? from whole string ?

Comment: Do you mean you have a string with only one number that is a whole word? Like `myname 804 805-way`? Yes. Perhaps, the regex can be restricted to spaces or string start/end: [`(?<=^|\s)\d+(?=\s|$)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5e%7c%5cs)%5cd%2b(%3f%3d%5cs%7c%24)&i=myname+804+805-way). Same can be done with the current regex for `myname`.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Please see [this IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/G3iwJ8).

Answer (score 1):

Do a replace using this regex:

```
(\s*\d+\-.{3}\s*|\s*.{3}\-\d+\s*)|(\s*\d+\s*)
```

you will end up with just your name.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cI7eL5/1)

Comment: Good One @NeverHopeless +1

Comment: But it also matches `1234` in `1234 myname 18-may`, see [this demo](http://rubular.com/r/q1dERE6Eey).

Comment: @stribizhev, what about now ?

Comment: @NeverHopeless: No idea, I am not sure if removing something you do not know for sure will fetch better results instead of matching what you know you need. Again, much depends on the input, and there were no specifications given, just a couple of examples.

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution without RegEx

```
string input = "myname 18-may 1234";
string result = input.Split(' ').Where(x => x.All(y => char.IsLetter(y))).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I like this LINQ approach, it will work until there are no context-dependent requirement from OP's part.